# NodeMCU interrupts triggering wrong IREs

Tags: interrupt, esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I'm kinda lost here with attaching interrupts for a V3 NodeMCU while programming it with the Arduino IDE.

So I've written this setup code:

```
void setup() {
  //declare output and input pins
  pinMode(D4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(D2, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(D2), buttonPressed, CHANGE);
  pinMode(D7, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(D7), motionDetected, CHANGE);
  //start the serial monitor (test purposes only)
  Serial.begin(115200);
  //initiate the EEPROM access and check stored values
  EEPROM.begin(512);
  getSetupVariables();
  //setup the wifi connection to previous set SSID and password
  setup_wifi();
  //set the MQTT server to previous declared values and set the callback function
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
  client.setCallback(handleMQTTCommands);
}
```

The interrupt ISRs are these two functions:

```
void buttonPressed() {
  if(!isBusy && digitalRead(D2) == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("button pressed");
    if(targetDoorState == DOOR_STATE_OPEN) {
      initiateOperation(DOOR_STATE_CLOSED);
    } else if(targetDoorState == DOOR_STATE_CLOSED) {
      initiateOperation(DOOR_STATE_OPEN);
    }
  }
}

void motionDetected() {
  char MQTT_channel[100];
  char msg[100];
  detachInterrupt(D7);
  MQTT_CHANNEL_SET_VALUE.toCharArray(MQTT_channel, (MQTT_CHANNEL_SET_VALUE.length() + 1));
  if(digitalRead(D7) == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("reached");
    String MQTT_PAYLOAD_OBSTRUCTION_DETECTED   = "{\"name\":\"" + DEVICE_NAME + "\", \"service_name\":\"garagedoor\",\"characteristic\":\"ObstructionDetected\", \"value\":"+ DOOR_STATE_OPEN +"}";
  } else if(digitalRead(D7) == LOW) {
    String MQTT_PAYLOAD_OBSTRUCTION_DETECTED   = "{\"name\":\"" + DEVICE_NAME + "\", \"service_name\":\"garagedoor\",\"characteristic\":\"ObstructionDetected\", \"value\":"+ DOOR_STATE_CLOSED +"}";
  }
  MQTT_PAYLOAD_OBSTRUCTION_DETECTED.toCharArray(msg, (MQTT_PAYLOAD_OBSTRUCTION_DETECTED.length() + 1));
  client.publish(MQTT_channel, msg);
  delay(500);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(D7), motionDetected, CHANGE);
}
```

So on pin D2 a button is attached. D7 has to listen to changes from a motion sensor. But when the motion sensor is triggered (thus the D7 interrupt needs to happen) both the D2 and D7 interrupt IREs are called. Does anyone have the same problem? Or sees what I'm doing wrong here?

I've tried different NodeMCU boards and all of them have this issue. I also searched for code examples, but all of them implement one `attachInterrupt`. When I comment out one of them, they work fine...

Thanks in advance!